# Insert Hyphen Between 2 Words for Use in URL in Python

Tags: python

I am scraping data to then use to access different links using Python and Selenium.

The issue I am having is that sometimes the subsection variable is two words instead of one. My code works ok when it is just one word but the URL syntax where there are two words requires a hyphen be inserted.

For example, where the section is "sport" and the subsection is "rugby league" the correct URL is https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/rugby-league.

What is the best way to insert a hyphen where there are two words?

```
section = []
subsection = []
base_url = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/'
final_url = f'{base_url}/{section}/{subsection}'
```

Comment: Replace spaces with hyphens…?

Comment: yes, exactly. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` should do the trick, no matter how many words are there in the string

```
x = "two words"
x = x.replace(' ', '-')
```

Answer (score 1):

if i got your question right:

```
subsection = [i.replace(' ', '-') for i in subsection]
```